# Could perchlorate salts allow for underwater combustion?

Tags: combustion

So apparently perchlorate salts can act as oxidizers for combustion (basically they can replace oxygen in the fire triangle, at least I think), and the reason why you can't have a fire underwater is because there's not enough oxygen gas in the water. So if one were to mix/dissolve perchlorate salts with a liquid fuel and made it hot, could the perchlorates allow it to combust?

Comment: Sodium metal doesn't need all that. Just pop it into the water -- outdoors, and surrounded by a good firebreak -- and watch what happens!

Comment: @OscarLanzi But then it is not underwater scenario.

Comment: You need fuel, oxidant and high enough temperature. Nobody says oxygen must be in free form. E.g. asymmetric dimethylhydrazine + NO2 as binary rocket propeller. It need not to be oxygen either. And fuel need not even to be  considered combustible. E.g. sand would burn if immersed in ClF3.

Comment: By other words, the mixture would burn even in vacuum. With water, there is condition for such a reaction to be so intense that water would not manage to cool it down and stop it.

Comment: Thermite is commonly used underwater, and makes a better choice, since neither aluminium nor ferric oxide is soluble in water, as are most chlorates. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CO5OKAo8aIw